# how can the qml files in qrc import plugins

Tags: python, pyqt, qml

I have one PyQt4 project, which use the qml files.
Now I want to add some qml files into the qrr file:

In qrc file:

```
<qresource prefix="/">
  <file>dir1/dir2/file1.qml</file>
  <file>dir1/dir2/file2.qml</file>
</qresource>
```

Use pyrcc4 tool to generate rc.py:

```
pyrcc4 -o source_rc.py source.qrc
```

Then, in the python script, I can call the qml files like:

```
import source_rc
....
qml_path = "qrc:/dir1/dir2/file1.qml"
```

But now I have one problem, because in my qml file, I have import the QtDestop component like this(the QtDeskop path is at /dir1/dir2/QtDesktop):

```
import "QtDesktop"
....
    CursorArea{
    .....
    }
```

So when I run my application, it will crash and report this:

```
qrc:/dir1/dir2/file1.qml:2:1 "QtDesktop": no such directory
```

Seems it can not find the QtDesktop path.
I try to add the full QtDestkop folder into the qrc, but there is one libstyleplugin.so plugin library in it, which can not be added into the qrc.

Is there anyone to help to resolve this problem? Thanks a lot!